# Convert string into path object

Tags: python, python-3.x, path, os.path

How do I convert a `string` into `path` objects?? Or how could I make `path` objects in python?
For example:
I need to use `path` objects in these:
`os.listdir(path)`
`os.chroot(path)`

Comment: Those are just strings.

Answer (score 2):

Both of those functions take string arguments. "path" there is simply the name of the argument.

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.chroot